# illegal option:- keystore when generating a keyhash

Tags: android, facebook

I have to do login with facebook so i am generating a key.

I am using below code in cmd but there is an error illegal option:- keystore.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\HiTeSh\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\Users\HiTeSh\openssl\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\HiTeSh\openssl\bin\openssl" base64
```

So what to do to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Download OpenSSL, and install it in your pc. and then try to run this command.
[openssl](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip&can=2&q=)

Comment: Thanks yes openssl is already downloaded and install in my pc

Comment: then check that what version of jdk is installed on your pc,

Comment: Simply try this.  C:\Users\xposs>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Comment: When i am using this the error come opensll is not recognized as an internal or external command can you please help me to solve this

Comment: Thanks for reply! now it giving error the system cannot find the path specified!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62567/discussion-between-gulnaz-ghanchi-and-hitesh-matnani).

Comment: keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\HiTeSh\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\Users\HiTeSh\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\HiTeSh\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64